# Creating if statement for the small program

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am currently struggling with my first java program.

The question's task was to create a program that prompts the user to enter 5 numbers and store them in an array. Then the array should be printed, after that's done the program prompts the user to enter a number to search. Depending on the number the program should print "(display number) is on the list" or "(display number) is not on the list"

I have been struggling with this for quite a while now not fully understanding the conditional task.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        // Enter three numbers
        System.out.print("Enter five numbers: ");
        int number1 = input.nextInt();
        int number2 = input.nextInt();
        int number3 = input.nextInt();
        int number4 = input.nextInt();
        int number5 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The sorted numbers are "
          + number1 + ", " + number2 + ", " + number3 + ", " + number4 + ", " + number5);

        System.out.println("Enter a number to search: ");


}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: What is your question? *"I'm struggling"* is very hard for anyone to answer.

Comment: lack of incompetence is not bad

Comment: Sorry, I haven't elaborated my question well enough. 

I don't understand how I can use the if statement when the user's input is stored in the integers

Comment: I strongly recommend doing some tutorials like those that @ZouZou linked to - as it stands your question is too broad for Stack Overflow - it isn't a tutorial site its a Question and Answer site.

Comment: @Paula Use an array as your assignment tells you. I don't see any array in your code.

Comment: You may also want to read _[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_ in the SO [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added comments to document what the code was doing. This should hopefully help you grasp the concept.

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
        //Create an array of integers to store user input
        int[] userNumbers = new int[5];
        System.out.print("Enter " userNumbers.length + " numbers: ");
        //Goes into a loop, and sets each array index to the user inputted integer
        for (int i = 0; i < userNumbers.length; i++) {
            userNumbers[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter a number you would like to search for");
        boolean exists = false;
        int numToSearch = input.nextInt();
        //for each number in the user numbers array, check to see if that number matches the number to search. If so, set exists = true and break out of the loop to check no further.
        for (int num: userNumbers) {
            if (numToSearch == num) {
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        //if else to decide which output to show the user.
        if (exists) {
            System.out.println(numToSearch + " is in the list");
        } else {
            System.out.println(numToSearch + " is not in the list");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Austin for the comments. I'll spend my time revising it now so I'll how to do it myself now <3

Answer (score -1):

At first instead of storing your numbers in single variables, you store them in an array. 
The next thing you'll do is use
    boolean tmp = false;
    int search = input.nextInt();
This will give you the number the user is searching for. 
When you have it (the program will wait at the instruction until there's input), you loop over your array and in each iteration you compare it to the given number. You do this by using 
    if (array[i] == search) {
    tmp = true} 
With i being your iteration variable. 
After the end of the for loop, you'll do another if where you, depending on the state of the tmp variable either print that the number exists or it doesn't. 
Sorry for short explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Try following....

```
public class NewClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// Enter three numbers
System.out.print("Enter five numbers: ");
int number1 = input.nextInt();
int number2 = input.nextInt();
int number3 = input.nextInt();
int number4 = input.nextInt();
int number5 = input.nextInt();

integers.add(number1);
integers.add(number2);
integers.add(number3);
integers.add(number4);
integers.add(number5);

System.out.println("The sorted numbers are "
  +integers);


    System.out.println("Enter a number to search: ");
int searchNum = input.nextInt();

if(integers.contains(seacrchNum)){
      System.out.println(searchNum+"  is on the list");
}else{
     System.out.println(searchNum+"  is not on the list");
}
}
```

Explainations :

Placed all the entered numbers into an arrayLists and then prompt for the search Number to be entered. and Check wheather the search number is der in the ArrayLists or not. Based on the condition display the Message

Comment: don't just post code, add an explanation as well.

Comment: "enter 5 numbers and store them in an array"

Comment: Instead of just providing an answer, can you add comments or text explaining what each piece does? Best way for the OP to learn is to fully understand what is going on :-)